# Image over navigation bar

Tags: html, css, image, overlap

I'm trying to overlap a image that covers two divs. I'm not too sure about how to set the position attribute for this and would like to what to do.  This is my code so far:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->

<div class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul>
                <li class="navLink">HOME</li>
                <li class="navLink">MENU</li>
                <li class="navLink">JOUW SMAAK</li>
                <li class="navLink">FOODTRUCK</li>
                <li style="padding-right: 0px;" class="navLink">CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- OPENING TIMES -->

<div class="opening-times">
    MAANDAG - VRIJDAG <span class="spacer"></span> 17:00 - 22:00
</div>

<!-- END OPENING TIMES -->

<!-- END NAVIGATION  -->
```

and this is the css.  I'd like to place an image over both the navigation section and the opening times.  Would I place a span over everything and do it from there?

```
    .navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 4%;
    padding: 7.5px 2% 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
}


.opening-times {
    font-size: 125%;
    background-color: rgb(31, 39, 45);
    color: rgb(109, 120, 125);
    padding: 5px 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.spacer {
    padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
}
```

Comment: So you would like the image to act as the background for the 2 elements?

Comment: I'm trying to get the image to overlap both the navigation section and the opening times section.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

Wrap the elements you want to cover with the image:

```
<div class="cover">
  Elements to cover here..
</div>
```

Then add these styles making the image the `background-image`:

```
.cover {
  position: relative;
}

.cover:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size:cover;
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100); /*Your image here*/
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fvx810v/1/) for a demo

Comment: Thanks, didn't work though. I thought of a similar idea.  Still to find a solution.